# How can i access anonymous types without FOREACHLOOP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq

How can i get test all data . i want to access test.stockdescid and test.barcode

please don't post :

```
foreach (var person in  myQuery)

    {

        Console.WriteLine(person);

    }
```

```
 var test =  (from s in stock.StockMaterials
                                              where (s.date<= DateTime.Now &&
                                              s.date.ToString() != "01/01/1900 00:00") &&
                                              s.id == ItemID &&
                                              s.chkdate == true
                                              select new { stockdescid= s.stockdescid,barcode=s.barcode});
                        if (ID.First() == ItemID)
                            ReturnMsg = "E1: Please check the expiry date : "+test.First().barcode.ToString();
```

Comment: your formatting is excellent.

Comment: errr.... what's the question?

Comment: You don't really need an anonymous type there do you? Why not just `select s`?

Comment: "your formatting is excellent. – Svisstack " is it joke? i dislike my formatting:)

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types can be accessed only from the method where they are created.

You say

> "i want to access test.stockdescid and
>   test.barcode"

But "test" is a collection, and the properties you want to access are on the items of the collection, not on the collection itself.

You don't have a test.barcode but rather test.First().barcode and so on.

That said, I don't clearly understand what you need to do. Can you try to be more clear about your goal?

Comment: Is it true? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "get test all data"?

You can write...

`test.ToList().ForEach(i => i.DoSomething());`

if that helps?

Comment: NO i need :  ReturnMsg = CardID_Barcode.ToList().ForEach(i => i.barcode.ToString());  thanks :)